# UIAlertView ios8 only showing a line for keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

**Problem:**

`UIAlertView` in iOS8 only showing a line for keyboard

Here is my **Code:**

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    UITextField *txtName = nil;

    if(buttonIndex == 1){ // save project name
        txtName = (UITextField *)[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

        if(txtName && txtName.text && [txtName.text length] > 0 && ![txtName.text isEqualToString:@" "]) {

            //SPAppDelegate *appdelegate = (SPAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            NSString *filePath = nil;

            //if(![appdelegate isProjectNameAlreadyExist:txtName.text]){
            if(![SPUtility isProjectNameAlreadyExist:txtName.text]){
                //filePath = [appdelegate getProjectPathWthName:txtName.text];
                filePath = [SPUtility getProjectPathWthName:txtName.text];
                [self loadProjectList];
            }
            else{
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Project name already exists." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            }
        }
        else{
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Project name is empty." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem must be happening somewhere here***

```
-(void) launchProjectNameInputAlert{

    /*_alertView = nil;

    _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test1" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [_alertView show];*/

    _isShowAlert = YES; //boolean variable

    //_alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ADD item" message:@"Put it blank textfield will cover this" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" " message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    UITextField *txtName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    txtName.text=@"";
    //txtName.tag = 1000;
    //[txtName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [txtName setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [txtName setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [txtName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    txtName.placeholder = @"Project Name";
    [alertView addSubview:txtName];
    [alertView show];

}
```

Can someone please check it out?

Here is a link of the **[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kksW5.png)** for reference.

Comment: Can you provide a picture or better elaborate your issue. Your code makes no sense when it's taken out of context. What do you mean by only showing a line for keyboard I'm assuming it's a textField but not sure, either way, we don't know what your vision is or what you WANT to happen.

Comment: I don't have a reputation enough to send a picture on here. My alert pop-up for my project list on my video editor works on ios7 now on ios8 it just pops up and shows a line where you would type the project. You can type anything to make a project anymore. It's standard iOS alert pop up

Comment: You can link pictures fyi

Comment: [IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2s0dz09.png[/IMG]

Comment: post it on dropbox.com or google or apple or any other picture sharing site and hyperlink it here

Comment: I"m not sure. Do you have any idea it worked just find on ios7. You could type in the box and keyboard would pop up to type in a new project.

Comment: Do you known how I could change that?

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the UIAlertView?

Comment: refer this for ios8 http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html

Comment: Just posted some more code, can one of you guys take a look? I can't create a project anymore on my app until I fix this.

Comment: Remove this line: `[alertView addSubview:txtName];` because the text field is already a subview.

Comment: Lindsey thank you. IT WORKED!!!!!!!  Can I ask one you a question really quickly if that's alright?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Colin has another question but isn't yet aware of tagging.

Comment: @soulshined thanks I was unaware of that

Answer (score 0):

Colin;

First, iOS 8 has deprecated the Alert View. Why? Because the new version is far more powerful and offers customization with ease. I understand you may feel like your controlling the outcome with clickedButtonAtIndex: however, these services are easily translated with the new UIAlertController. For one, you don't need a delegate and two, everything is done in blocks. Additionally the same UIAlertController provides the Alert or the Action Sheet. They are no longer separate.

Here is an example :

```
UIAlertController *alertC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet]; // Populates an action Sheet

UIAlertController *alertC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; //Alert
```

Then you simply add actions to them

```
UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
```

Add the actions to the UIAlertController and present it to the view either animated or nil:

```
[alertC addAction:action];
[self presentViewController:alertC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

There are numerous tutorials out there to duplicate your desired outcome.

[Use Your Loaf](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html) seems to have done an outstanding job in step-by-step tutorials for those stuck on UIAlertViews.

I would suggest to take advantage of this new method because you can handle all your code in blocks instead of lengthy if statements. It's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm going to check that out maybe I can get mine to work. I just really don't know where to begin to change things around.

Comment: I"m trying to figure it out, I'm reading it right now, there's just so much code, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. I'm not a coder, just been reading some books on it trying to get a grip. I've had someone building a video editor for me, and now I can't get that project screen to work. I'll try to follow the steps in your link.